# where condition - ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Tags: sql, oracle

In my where condition i need to put a check that a particular date column is not equal to a specific date.. How can i do this

Currently i have written

```
gsaTs.X_GSA_ARRIVE_ONSITE <> '1753/01/01'
```

I am getting the following error

```
[Error] Execution (189: 49): ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: `'1753/01/01'` is a string. If `X_GS_ARRIVE_ONSITE` column is `DATE` datatype, you should provide format mask (with the `TO_DATE` function), or use `DATE` literal, e.g.

```
gsats.x_gsa_arrive_onsite <> to_date('1753/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

or

```
gsats.x_gsa_arrive_onsite <> date '1753-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `to_date()` and specify a matching format string.

```
gsaTs.X_GSA_ARRIVE_ONSITE <> to_date('1753/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```